# Maven dependencyManagement in parent when using child as module failes due to execution order

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Is there an easier way to force maven to build the parent before the modules ?

Use case:
I'm trying to understand what is the best practice to solve the following problem

I have two projects that I will name 'A' and 'B'
They both have a parent that I will name 'P'

'P' have a dependency management for shared resources this will allow using the same version for shared artifacts.

'P' is also used to run 'A' and 'B' as modules.

The problem:
When a new artifact is added I'm adding the version in 'P' and the dependency at 'A' (for example). now when doing a maven clean install I'm getting 'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for .

This is due to the fact that maven first builds it's modules before himself and then 'A' doesn't have the version.

I know that I can put in 'A' pom under  the following:
../
and it works (but no always).

Back to my question: is there an easier way to force maven to build the parent before the modules ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that my problem was not only the relative path as mentioned above but the fact that my parent pom version was a variable ${version} and was not replaced during build.

To solve this issue I hard coded wrote the parent version in the parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, that is the situation where modules' parent == modules' aggregator, Maven should build parents before their modules as long as they're in the same build reactor and that usually means you should build all modules from the `P` project level. And even if you don't, parents should be resolved right if your have proper `<relativePath`> tags in your `<parent>` blocks within modules' `pom.xml` (look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Example_2) for example). By default there is `..` value there which means that artifact's parent is in the parent directory in filesystem.